# How to specify ID variables in dcast?

Tags: r, reshape2, dcast

Following is a sample of the data I have

```
datahave
# A tibble: 6 x 6
   YEAR SCHOOL_NAME              CONTENT_AREA       BELOW_BASIC_PCT    BASIC_PCT          ADVANCED_PCT
  <dbl> <chr>                    <chr>              <chr>              <chr>              <chr>       
1  2015 5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.   Eng. Language Arts 38.1               28.3               10.1        
2  2015 5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.   Mathematics        39                 30.3               14.6        
3  2015 5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.   Science            25.4               41.7               12.3        
4  2015 6TH GRADE CENTER         Eng. Language Arts 7.6                27.8               21.8        
5  2015 6TH GRADE CENTER         Mathematics        19.100000000000001 37.700000000000003 17.5        
6  2015 7th and 8th Grade Center Eng. Language Arts 52.1               27.4               1.7
```

Following is a reproducible example similar to this

```
school<-c("A","A",'A','B','B','B')
content_area<-c('english','math','science','english','math','science')
below_basic<-c(20,30,40,10,15,20)
advanced<-c(2,5,3,1,2.5,1.5)


df<-data.frame(school,content_area,below_basic,advanced)
df
```

and ran the following code on the above

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(df), school ~ content_area + variable)
```

This gives me the desired output because it is using `Using school, content_area as id variables`

However when I run the same code on the original dataset

```
dcast(melt(datahave), SCHOOL_NAME ~ CONTENT_AREA + variable)
```

it is actually using Using `SCHOOL_NAME, CONTENT_AREA, BELOW_BASIC_PCT, BASIC_PCT, ADVANCED_PCT as id variables`

How do I specify which columns can be used as the ID variable? so I get an output similar to the reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can specify the `id.var` in `melt`, otherwise, it can automatically pick the variables based on the type.

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(melt(datahave, id.var = c("YEAR", "SCHOOL_NAME", "CONTENT_AREA")), 
              SCHOOL_NAME ~ CONTENT_AREA + variable)
#           SCHOOL_NAME Eng. Language Arts_BELOW_BASIC_PCT Eng. Language Arts_BASIC_PCT
#1   5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.                               38.1                         28.3
#2         6TH GRADE CENTER                                7.6                         27.8
#3 7th and 8th Grade Center                               52.1                         27.4
#  Eng. Language Arts_ADVANCED_PCT Mathematics_BELOW_BASIC_PCT Mathematics_BASIC_PCT Mathematics_ADVANCED_PCT
#1                            10.1                        39.0                  30.3                     14.6
#2                            21.8                        19.1                  37.7                     17.5
#3                             1.7                          NA                    NA                       NA
#  Science_BELOW_BASIC_PCT Science_BASIC_PCT Science_ADVANCED_PCT
#1                    25.4              41.7                 12.3
#2                      NA                NA                   NA
#3                      NA                NA                   NA
```

---

The `melt/dcast` wrapper is `recast` which can be used as well

```
recast(datahave, id.var = c("YEAR", "SCHOOL_NAME", "CONTENT_AREA"), 
       SCHOOL_NAME ~ CONTENT_AREA + variable)
```

#### data

```
datahave <- structure(list(YEAR = c(2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L, 2015L
), SCHOOL_NAME = c("5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.", "5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.", 
"5TH AND 6TH GRADE CTR.", "6TH GRADE CENTER", "6TH GRADE CENTER", 
"7th and 8th Grade Center"), CONTENT_AREA = c("Eng. Language Arts", 
"Mathematics", "Science", "Eng. Language Arts", "Mathematics", 
"Eng. Language Arts"), BELOW_BASIC_PCT = c(38.1, 39, 25.4, 7.6, 
19.1, 52.1), BASIC_PCT = c(28.3, 30.3, 41.7, 27.8, 37.7, 27.4
), ADVANCED_PCT = c(10.1, 14.6, 12.3, 21.8, 17.5, 1.7)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```